# Unloading external swf files on online portfolio

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using this code to unload a swf file and go back to the main menu. The main menu has no trouble loading the external swf files but for some reason unloading just doesn't work :s

```
var BaseMovie:MovieClip = parent.parent as MovieClip;

BaseMovie.loader.unload();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the object is a parent of the object that is making the function call, which means that it has to remain an active reference.  More code will be needed to give a better answer.

Comment: What code would that be? Just a note that this code worked until yesterday and suddenly stopped working...

Comment: I don't know what code it would be.  All of it?  Or just post the code that causes the problem.

Comment: The code to fix the problem... Like I said this code worked 24 hours ago

Comment: Dunno.  Maybe more details could help; though you will probably have to do some debugging and find more info before anyone will be able to offer help.